# how to add a date variable in sql string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query that is being built based on some data and I need to be able to add the `@StartDate` parameter in the string but I get the following error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Part of the query is like this:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
DECLARE @where = ''
...

SET @where = @where + '(initDate BETWEEN ' + @StartDate + ' AND ' + @EndDate + ')'
```

How can I add the `StartDate` and `EndDate` there without causing this issue? I tried `CONVERT(DATETIME, @StartDate)` , but get the same issue

Comment: What was the string you passed?

Comment: a datetime like 01/01/2010 12:00 AM

Comment: Your example is ambiguous.  Which is the day and which is the month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SET @where = @where + '(initDate BETWEEN ' + convert(varchar(10),@StartDate,104) + ' AND ' + convert(varchar(10),@EndDate,104) + ')'
```

OR

```
SET @where = @where + '(initDate BETWEEN ' + convert(varchar(10),@StartDate,106) + ' AND ' + convert(varchar(10),@EndDate,106) + ')'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [CAST or CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to change @StartDate and @EndDate to a string. Choose an appropriate method as per the link that gives you the level of precision you need.